# External content type based on OData is invisible in SPD2013 (but visible in a web browser)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, external-content-type, 2013, odata

I am trying to connect external list based on OData to Outlook, I could create it, but can't map its fields to Office Item type because it is invisible in SPD2013.

I made screenshots of all the steps to repeat the issue.

**Step1. Create BDC model. You can skip this step and download bdcm file [here](http://pastebin.com/6LzbQYWy)**

1. Create new SharePoint 2013 app project.
   [image]
2. Add new Item / Content Types for an External Data Source
   [image]
3. Add test OData service info.
   [image]
4. Select the only entity - Regions
   [image]
5. Press the Deploy button (to generate WSP where we can get bdcm file), like it shown in [this article](http://benredl.wordpress.com/2012/11/08/external-list-using-an-odata-source-in-sharepoint-2013-based-on-a-farm-wide-bcd-model/).

At the end of this step I have [BDCMetadata.bdcm](http://pastebin.com/6LzbQYWy) file, which I get from the myproject.wsp\MyFeature\External Content Types.

**Step2. Import the model to Business Data Connectivity Service.**

1. Go to the Central Administration \ Application Management \ Manage Service Applications \ Bussiness Data Connectivity Service \ Import.
   [image]
2. Choose my bdcm file and press the Import button.
   [image]
3. After  that I can see my model in Web Browser.
   [image]
   But I can't see it in SPD2013. 
   [image]

**What I tried**

- press the refresh button, trying to make a clean installation of the SPD to another machine. Result is the same, I can't see it.
- create External list using a web browser (Settings \ Add an app \ External list). I could see external content type

[image]

and even could create list, which worked well.

[image]

I can see this external list in SPD2013 too, but all the same I can't see the external content type.

**Does anybody have any ideas?**
Every suggestions are very appreciated.

**UPDATE1**: Maybe there is another way to map external content type to the Office Item type without using SPD?

PS: [link to this question on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/0a1cf197-0aa5-481d-aa80-074507b28d8c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that it happens because SPD2013 doesn't support OData. So possibly somebody knows the answer on the following question:
[Is it possible to map External Content Type to Office Item Type without using SharePoint Designer?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52600/is-it-possible-to-map-external-content-type-to-office-item-type-without-using-sh)